# Populate Master view of SplitViewController with data from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, asynchronous, uisplitviewcontroller

I have SplitViewController in which i have to populate the master view (the left view) with data from server. I have fetched the data. The issue i am facing is that the master view is shown first empty but the response from server comes after some time as the data set is large. After the data is completely received and parsed i try to load that in `viewDidLoad` of MasterViewController, but the array is empty so the MasterView also shows empty rows. What could be the most appropriate place/delegates for splitviewcontroller so that i can show splitviewcontroller only after i get complete data from server and then show that data in master view

Answer (score 0):

You should update all view (reload table view, redraw views, etc.) after data is ready. Read about MVC (model-view-controller) pattern to understand more about such issues.